# Mono (.NET) on Scientific Linux 6

Tags: .net-framework, scientific-linux, mono-framework

I'm very new to Linux. I need to start .NET application on Scientific Linux 6. I read that I need to install Mono first but I can't figure out how to do this, because on the official website there is no Download Section for Scientific Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scientific Linux is based on RedHat.

If Scientific Linux don't provide package repositories, I would use those of CentOS (another distribution also based on RedHat). Use the package manager `yum` to find and install mono

Answer (score 1):

The [**EPEL** repository](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) created by the Fedora Project, provides packages for [**Mono**](http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/repoview/mono-core.html). As of June 2014, it provides version 2.4.3.1.